# Readings on modern algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I have read Pinter's book ***A Book of Abstract Algebra*** and I want to go deeper in the subject.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Two long volumes on abstract algebra by Anthony Knapp are [freely available from his website](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~aknapp/download.html). This is a fresh reedition; let him know if you find bugs!

Comment: there are a lot of recommendations, at various levels, of abstract algebra. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbook-recommendation%5D+abstract+algebra) by example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the book you mention, but you might want to look into representation theory. A good reference is Fulton's book on the subject